# How does memory management in Python work for integers?

Tags: python, memory-management

The result in the two following examples is different:

**EXAMPLE 1**

```
a = 845
b = int("8"+"4"+"5")

print(a == b) # True
print(a is b) # False
```

**EXAMPLE 2**

```
a = 845
b = 840+5

print(a == b) # True
print(a is b) # True
```

How can it be explained? Why in the first case the same integer is kept in two different memory slots in the pile?

I expected the result to be the same (True) in both cases.

Comment: @Brian61354270 even if it's not between -5 and 256?

Comment: @Daviid Yes, that is covered in the answers to that question. E.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49472348/11082165) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34964030/11082165)

Comment: You can check here to see that Example 2 comes down to examples displayed in these comments ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49472348/11082165)):

https://godbolt.org/z/xKacd5oh4

That addition is done in compile time, so the compiled output acts as if you hardcoded both values to 845.

We can use the same tool to understand why example 1 does not behave this way:
https://godbolt.org/z/a34r6ro6T

Comment: @EnsarSarajcic does that answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77432232/python-in-jupyter-notebook-integers-and-is-operator too?

Comment: I think it does, it looks like the same thing to me. I assume running it in Jupyter Notebook skips compilation.

Comment: memory management works the exact same way as it does for other objects in CPython: reference counting

Comment: "I expected the result to be the same (True) in both cases." **why would you expect that**?

Comment: @EnsarSarajcic you cannot "skip compilation".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers) provides good context on this issue, but this is a bit different to the cases mentioned there (but it comes down to the same thing in the end). Even though only integers between -5 and 256 are cached and return `True` for `is` checks, the same happens for hardcoded integers, since they are compiled as constants and are not allocated.

Using [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/) makes this a bit easier to understand. First example can also be written as

```
a = 845
b = int("845")

print(a == b) # True
print(a is b) # False
```

We can see in https://godbolt.org/z/zM3haedb9 that string concatenation is done in compile-time, but `int` is called in the end again, which creates a new integer and since it is not in the cached range, a new object is created, making `is` return `False`.

For second example, addition is done in compile team, making it equivalent to

```
a = 845
b = 845

print(a == b) # True
print(a is b) # True
```

Which with the help of [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers) makes complete sense.

You can check out https://godbolt.org/z/xKacd5oh4 to see that after compilation, both `a` and `b` are created the same way.

Comment: "since they are compiled as constants and are not allocated." this is nonsense. of course they are allocated. How else do you expect an `int` object to exist? It exists on the privately managed heap. CPython does not work like C or C++. Everything is an object that exists on the privately managed heap