# Python in Jupyter notebook, integers and is operator

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Reading these [How does memory management in Python work for integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77432108/how-does-memory-management-in-python-work-for-integers) and ["is" operator behaves unexpectedly with integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/306313/is-operator-behaves-unexpectedly-with-integers)

I was testing

```
a = 845
b = int("8"+"4"+"5")

print(a == b) # True
print(a is b) # False
print(id(a))
print(id(b))

a = 845
b = 840+5

print(a == b) # True
print(a is b) # True
print(id(a))
print(id(b))
```

If you run this code in python by copypasting or, as I was doing, shift+enter (notebook.cell.executeAndSelectBelow) in vscode to run it in Jupyter Notebook you get all different memory addresses.

```
True
False
2832156355920
2832156352912
True
False
2832156355888
2832156355696
```

If you save it as a file and run it by `python main.py` you get the first a and the second a and b share memory address.

```
True
False
1612814393360
1612814397168
True
True
1612814393360
1612814393360
```

Why? What's different int the interpreter when copypasting line by line and using Jupyter Notebook? I assume the `line by line` part but why?

Comment: Yes, thank you!